# How to show only UK postcodes in results

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-2

I have created a form on my website that allows a user to enter a postcode into a form and then find the nearest match to a postcode of my locations that I store in a database and show the distance between these two locations

This works fine when a valid postcode is put in but sometimes when either an invalid postcode is put in or when there is a similar location elsewhere around the world it will return a strange address. For example, one of the postcodes in my database is cr4 but when just he value 'cr' is put into my finder it will return the location 'California' as the starting point which is incorrect.

My question is, is there anyway to allow Google Maps API to only search for postcode locations? I have searched with in the documentation and can't seem to see this anywhere.

Here is my code:

An example of one of the locations in my database:

```
 {
    address1: "Unit 2",
    address2: "Leslie Retail Park",
    address3: "Boucher Road",
    address4: "Belfast",
    postcode: "BT12 6HH",
    name: "Belfast",
    lat: 54.577708,
    lon: -5.961649,
    opening_hours: "Mon-Thu: 6:30 AM - 10:00 PM ^Fri: 6:30 AM - 8:00 PM ^Sat-Sun: 9:00 AM - 5:00 PM ^Bank Holidays: 9:00 AM - 5:00 PM",
    bank_holidays: "",
    id: 1,
    targetpage: "<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/index.php/our-gyms/fitspace-belfast",
    image: "<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/images/belfast.jpg"
  }
```

and my Google Maps API search code:

```
var geocoder, location1, location2;

    jQuery('#postcode_search_form').submit(function(e) {    
        e.preventDefault();
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        geocoder.getLocations(document.forms[0].postcode_search.value, function (response) {    
           if (response || response.Status.code != 200) {
                location1 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
                calculateDistance();
            }
        });
    });

    function calculateDistance()
    {
        var closeClubs = [];
        var sortable = [];
        var resultsArray = new Array();
        try {   
            jQuery(gyms).each(function(i, v) {
                var glatlng1 = new GLatLng(location1.lat, location1.lon);
                var glatlng2 = new GLatLng(v.lat, v.lon);
                var miledistance = glatlng1.distanceFrom(glatlng2, 3959).toFixed(1);
                if(miledistance <= 50) {
                    gyms[i].distance = miledistance;
                    closeClubs.push(v);
                }

                var kmdistance = (miledistance * 1.609344).toFixed(1);  
            });
            closeClubs.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.distance - b.distance;
            });
            document.getElementById('club_search_start').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('club_search_start').innerHTML = '<strong>Your location: </strong>' + location1.address;

            var html = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < closeClubs.length; i++) {
                html += "<div class='club'>";
                    html += "<div class='result_left'><img src='" + closeClubs[i].image + "' /></div>";
                    html += "<div class='result_right'><a href='" + closeClubs[i].targetpage + "'>" + closeClubs[i].name + "</a>"; 
                    html += "<p class='club_postcode'>" + closeClubs[i].postcode + "</p>";
                    html += "<p class='club_description'>" + closeClubs[i].opening_hours + "</p>";  
                    html += "<p class='distance'>Distance:" + closeClubs[i].distance + " miles </p>";
                    html += "</div>"
                html += "</div>"
            }
            jQuery('#club_search_results').hide().html(html).fadeIn('slow');
        }
        catch (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    }   
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: The Maps API has a `region` parameter that may help a bit: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en#RegionCodes It's just a biasing mechanism, though, not a hard limitation.

Comment: Hi,thanks! This may help as requests will generally only be made from within the UK (hopefully!) I will take a look.

Comment: Ok I understand how that works but I am unsure as to how I would implement that into my code? Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: You're using the old API v2, which has been deprecated sine 2010, and will eventually stop working.  Indeed it was meant to have stopped in May 2013, but they've extended that deadline until November.  You should definitely rewrite all your JS to use API v3 instead

Comment: Hi yes I just noticed that too. I will go and rewrite this. Thanks